# Import sql dump backup file to my sql server using git bash in windows 10

Tags: mysql, bash, mysqlimport

I exported (dumped) a .sql file from my remote Linux server and would like to import it to my local MYSQL server (windows 10) using bash command in git bash.

`mysql -u root -p  DBname  <  C:/Users/.../sb_backup.sql`

after this command it asks me for my MYSQL client password and then it freezes forever. When I ctr+C and go back and check, I see it has not been imported yet.

I already created DBname and it exists.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Try part of the sql file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean! Can u please clarify your question?
BTW, I am trying to import the entire db_backup.sql into MySQL server for my web application.

Comment: Just try to import a small part of your SQL file and see if you can do it successfully.